# Use pivot to change rows to columns for sequencing data using sql

Tags: sql, pivot, oracle12c

I have data in a view where the Col_Head column values are supposed to be column headers(they are constant for every sequence of data from 1-8.

And `Value` column entries need to come as row values.

I need to write some SQL that transposes/pivots rows from Col_Head as column headers.

Example:

[image]

Expected data:

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please edit your question and add the tag accordingly. Also Mention the version.E.g `Oracle 11c`,`MySQL`, `MSSQL 2012` etc.,

Comment: oracle 12c,updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a specific Id for each person then you didn't need to create CTE, any way

First, I create specific Id for each person like this via `CTE`:
[image: sp_id]

```
   /*Create CTE*/
    With tempTable as
    (
    select  
     row_number() over( order by(select 0) ) row_num,
    *
    from myTable
    ),newTable as(
    
    select 
    case when (row_num %8)>0 then (row_num /8)+1 else (row_num /8) end sp_Id,
    *
    from tempTable 
    )  

  /*MainQuery*/  
    select 
    *
    from (select sp_id, Col_Header,[Value] from newTable )as temp 
    pivot
    (
    max([Value])
    for Col_Header in ([Emp name],[Emp Dept],[Emp Grade],[Emp class],[Emp Sal],[Emp manager],[Emp Date of join],[Emp documents])
    ) pivotTable
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, can this be done dynamically also? without hardcoding column headers? something like pivot xml? I tried using xml keyword,didn't work

Comment: are you using Oracle or SQL?

Comment: oracle database